# Could not normalize path in bintrayUpload

Tags: android, build.gradle, gradlew

I get following error while running `gradlew install`.

> Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'javadoc' during up-to-date check. See stacktrace for details.
>
> Could not normalize path for file 'C:\android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar;C:\android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar'

The project's build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The library module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'


ext {
bintrayRepo = 'maven'
bintrayName = 'befrest'

publishedGroupId = 'com.oddrun.libraries'
libraryName = 'Befrest'
artifact = 'befrest'

libraryDescription = 'Simple Push Notification Library For Android'

siteUrl = 'https://github.com/hojjat-imani/PushNotif'
gitUrl = 'https://github.com/hojjat-imani/PushNotif.git'

libraryVersion = '0.0.1'

developerId = 'hojjat-imani'
developerName = 'Hojjat Imani'
developerEmail = 'imani.hojjat95@gmail.com'

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 0
    versionName "0.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}




version = libraryVersion

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
classifier = 'javadoc'
from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
archives javadocJar
archives sourcesJar
}

// Bintray
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

bintray {
user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

configurations = ['archives']
pkg {
    repo = bintrayRepo
    name = bintrayName
    desc = libraryDescription
    websiteUrl = siteUrl
    vcsUrl = gitUrl
    licenses = allLicenses
    publish = true
    publicDownloadNumbers = true
    version {
        desc = libraryDescription
        gpg {
            sign = true //Determines whether to GPG sign the files. The default is false
            passphrase = properties.getProperty("bintray.gpg.password")
            //Optional. The passphrase for GPG signing'
        }
    }
}
}



group = publishedGroupId                               // Maven Group ID for the artifact

install {
repositories.mavenInstaller {
    // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
    pom {
        project {
            packaging 'aar'
            groupId publishedGroupId
            artifactId artifact

            // Add your description here
            name libraryName
            description libraryDescription
            url siteUrl

            // Set your license
            licenses {
                license {
                    name licenseName
                    url licenseUrl
                }
            }
            developers {
                developer {
                    id developerId
                    name developerName
                    email developerEmail
                }
            }
            scm {
                connection gitUrl
                developerConnection gitUrl
                url siteUrl

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Comment: @lopez.mikhael checkout my answere

Comment: @user3903725 I think I fond a better solution. Check my answere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` in your libs folder.
You can find this jar in `Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional`

I also added this line to my `app.gradle` file

```
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
```

But if you're using more libraries, you can use this way

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

This resolved all my errors that were caused because google removed support of Apache HTTP client. Do not changed `compileSdkVersion 23` to `22`, I think this solution is better.

Comment: I suggest use `provided files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')`,  so the dependency will be not included in the apk.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with apache http in android 23.
Just changing `compileSdkVersion 23` to 22 and removing `useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'` solved the problem.